# How to filter a ListView using edit text and SimpleCursor Adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview

More than one person have had the problem of how to implement a Filter for a ListView that uses a SimpleCursorAdapter. I had this problem and I have found lots of answers about this in this web. I have taken pieces of code from everywhere until I finally got it work and it was simpler that it looked like.

I've seen the Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView video on youtube and it says that you have to implement getFilter method and implements Filterable on your class adapter, something like this:

```
public class MyListCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements Filterable{

...
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter(){
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence){
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            //If there's nothing to filter on, return the original data for your list
            if(charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0){
                results.values = originalData;
                results.count = originalData.getCount();
            }
            else{

                Cursor filterResultsData = null;

                filterResultsData = DB.getResults(charSequence);

                results.values = filterResultsData;
                results.count = filterResultsData.getCount();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults){
            filteredData = (Cursor) filterResults.values;
            if (filterResults.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else{
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
}
}
```

At least is what I tried to do. I've seen that using ArrayAdapter instead of Cursor, works pretty well. But in the case of Cursor it didn't work, at least not for me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. So I was a little confused about what do to. I know that I have a edit text, a list view and everytime a put some text on my edit text I want my list get filtered.

Now I'm going to answer my own question since I want to share with you my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is What I have done:

**Layout:**

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="@string/search" >
</EditText>


<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:textFilterEnabled="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Pay attention to android:textFilterEnabled="true" in ListView.

**My ListActivity or ListFragment:**

```
public class ClientesActivity extends ListFragment {

private MyListCursorAdapter myAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_clientes, container, false);

            //call to a method that fill my list
    myListGetFilled(view);

            //Put a listener to edit text search
    EditText etSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
    etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            myAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });


    return view;
}

    private void myListGetFilled(View view){

    Cursor mCursor = DB.fillMyList(getActivity());

    if(mCursor.getCount()>0){

        String[] from = new String[] { "name", "description"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textViewName,  R.id.textViewDescription};

        ListView myListView = (ListView) view.findViewById (android.R.id.list);

        myAdapter = new MyListCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.activity_row_list, mCursor, from, to);
        myListView .setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }
}
```

**And finally my custom cursor adapter:**

```
public class MyListCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements Filterable{

     ...

   /*THE METHOD THAT DOES THE MAGIC*/
   public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {

    if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null){ 
        return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint); 
    }

    Cursor filterResultsData = DB.getResults(constraint);
    return filterResultsData;
  }
}
```

And that's it!!.

Hope this can be useful to anyone. And if you think there is a better solution than this one, please share!!.